# Row with dynamic number of columns in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, razor

I have a Razor page that displays a collection of thumbnail images in a vertical stack:

```
@foreach (var photo in Model)
{
    <div>@photo.PhotoId</div>
    <div>@photo.Title</div>
    <div>
        <img src="@photo.LargeSquareThumbnailUrl" alt="Many cups!" />
    </div>
}
```

However, what I have been trying to do is stack the images horizontally on one row.  And if it overflows (which it nearly always will do) then to display with a horizontal scroll bar.

I guess I would handle the overflow in CSS, but I am unable to work out how to stack the images in the first place.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a container with white-space:nowrap and put each pod as inline block:

```css
.container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>@photo.PhotoId</div>
    <div>@photo.Title</div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Many cups!" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>@photo.PhotoId</div>
    <div>@photo.Title</div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Many cups!" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>@photo.PhotoId</div>
    <div>@photo.Title</div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Many cups!" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>@photo.PhotoId</div>
    <div>@photo.Title</div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Many cups!" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>@photo.PhotoId</div>
    <div>@photo.Title</div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Many cups!" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>@photo.PhotoId</div>
    <div>@photo.Title</div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Many cups!" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>@photo.PhotoId</div>
    <div>@photo.Title</div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Many cups!" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>@photo.PhotoId</div>
    <div>@photo.Title</div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Many cups!" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>@photo.PhotoId</div>
    <div>@photo.Title</div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Many cups!" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>@photo.PhotoId</div>
    <div>@photo.Title</div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Many cups!" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great.  I moved the wrapper into my loop.  Thank you